# How can we find an example of derivation on commutative rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

$R$ is an commutative ring and an additive map $d:R \to R$ such that $d(xy)=d(x)y+xd(y)$.
 I need examples of derivations on basic commutative rings, for example $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{Z}_p$, $\mathbb{Q}$. If we take $a \in R$ and all $ x\in R$, then $[a,x]=ax-xa=0$ because $R$ is commutative, so all inner derivation is zero. So I don't want to find zero derivation as a example.

Comment: If your definition of a derivation is an additive map $d:R\to R$ such that $d(ab)=ad(b)+bd(a)$, then there are no non-zero ones for $\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}_p,\mathbb{Q}$. What is $R$ in your question?

Comment: Yes u are right.R is an commutaive ring and  an additive mapping $d:R \to R$ such that $d(ab)=d(a)b+ad(b)$.We can say there are no non-zero inner derivation ones for $\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Z}_p,\mathbb{Q}$,but maybe we can construct outer derivation on $\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Z}_p,\mathbb{Q}$.how can u say all of derivations are zero.

Comment: Two basic examples are Examples 1.7 and 1.8 in http://web.mit.edu/~darij/www/algebra/derivat.pdf . (You should take $\mathbf{k} = \mathbb{Z}$, $A = R$ and $M = R$.)

Comment: 1.7 polynomial and 1.8 isn't acquaintant for me.I need easier example then yours :).

Comment: @darijgrinberg Dear Mr. Darij, i follow link you've given and it is no longer anymore, would you please renew the link?

Comment: @RezaHabibi: the correct link is http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/derivat.pdf .

Comment: @darijgrinberg thanks for your favor Mr. Darij!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me expand on the comment Emrah Korkmaz made:

> There are no nonzero derivations on $\mathbb Z, \mathbb Z_p, \mathbb Q$.

First of all, for any derivation $d$, $d(1) = 0$. This follows from
\begin{equation}
d(1) = d(1 * 1) = d(1) + d(1).
\end{equation}
Since $d$ is additive we have therefore on any ring that the value of $d$ on the integers vanishes.

Let us take a look on fractions:
Suppose $b$ is a non-zero divisor and invertible. We have
\begin{equation}
0 = d(1) = d(\frac{b}{b}) = b d( \frac{1}{b} ) + d(b) \frac{1}{b}
\end{equation}
therefore $d(\frac{1}{b}) = - \frac{1}{b}^2 d(b)$.

From $ d( \frac{a}{b} ) = a d( \frac{1}{b} ) + d(a) \frac{1}{b} = - \frac{a}{b^2} d(b) + d(a) \frac{1}{b}$ we get that $d$ even vanishes on all fractions of integers.

This settles the case for the above rings.

Now, there could still be a nonzero derivation on $\mathbb R$, but since its value on the rationals must vanish it has to be discontinuous. I assume proving the existence of one (if it can be done) is highly nontrivial, and requires the axiom of choice.

Comment: thank you so much Georg Lehner.your answer is really  explanatory.

Comment: @Georg Lehner, please would you explain what does it mean by vanish in $\mathbb{R} on your comment? and would you also explain how to get the nonzero derivation in $\mathbb{R}$ that fits your comment?